# Multi-user MFA for Google Authenticator based logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

Our company manages hundreds of accounts that we need to protect using Google Authenticator (mainly AWS accounts, but other services as well).
The accounts don't allow multiple users so all relevant personnel needs to access the accounts using the same Google Authenticator.

We've thought about using WinAuth - but it has no access controls.

Is there any service/software that can allow us to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Simply **take a picture of the MFA QR code** or save the seed code and load it to *Google Authenticator* apps on as many devices as you need. They will all generate the same codes as it’s time-based.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can work with multiple users.

1. When setting up google authenticator use MFA key/secret rather than image scraping.
2. Save the MFA key into keepass or some other key management tool and protect the same with master password and keyfile etc.
3. Share the credentials of the keepass with whosoever you want to share.
4. When individual want to loging they can pull required MFA key from keepass and add into either own authenticator and new seeds can be generated.